# Calculating view distance from satellite

Tags: trigonometry

Imagine a satellite equipped with a camera is orbiting the earth. If the camera has a view angle of 63° and is 870km above the surface of the earth, is it possible to calculate the total distance it can see? if yes, how can I do it? [link to illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SV7Q.png)

Comment: Perhaps draw a second pair of triangles, to the centre of the planet?

Comment: Hint: What is the angle, calculated from the centre of the planet? That (in radians) multiplied by the radius ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Draw another set of segments from where your rays hit the planet to the planets center then one from the 'center' to the center of the planet - like in the horrible picture below. You can use the radius of the planet and a bit of geometry to find the angle $\theta$ in the diagram (keep in mind you must be in radians!).

[image]

Assuming your planet is (approximately) spherical, you then can use $s= r\theta$, where $s$ is the arclength, $r$ is the radius of the planet, and $\theta$ is the total angle covered. So in your case, you will then have
$$
\text{Total Distance}=2d= r (2\theta)= 2r \theta
$$
There is very similar to the approach of finding planetary distances using vectors and the above formula in [the project found here](https://coffeeintotheorems.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/Fall/MAT397/Applied/2020_fall_mat397_app_geometrysol.pdf).

**EDIT.** Because you asked, you can find the angle $\theta$ using the law of cosines (there may be more clever ways, but it is late and I will go with the first thing that comes to mind).

[image]

Consider the (equally ugly) diagram above. Call $d$ the distance above the Earth the satellite is, $t$ your angle, and call $r$ the radius of the planet. Let's define $R:= r+d$, i.e. the hypotenuse of the large triangle we formed. We can apply law of cosines, $r^2= S^2 + R^2 - 2SR \cos t$ to find the third side of the triangle, which we will call $S$. Then we can use the law of cosines again in $S^2= r^2 + R^2 - 2rR \cos \theta$ to find our angle $\theta$.

Comment: Could you go more in-depth about finding angle θ? If I can't treat the top side of the triangle as a straight line, I am lost. :D

Comment: Is it so that the beams that define view angle, hit the planet surface parallel to the ground? In other words, is the angle between the beam, and the radius of the planet, 90 degrees at that point?

Comment: @MattiP. Sorry if this is simple, but can you elaborate more?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that the sides of the 63° will make 90 degrees with the radius lines?

Comment: @Blobtoe It will only make angle 90 if it were tangent to the planet, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Blobtoe At least the way I read it, the camera aperture cannot necessarily widen enough to see the 'horizon' it is able to see given its distance above the planet - rather it just 'sees what it can'. If this is the case, then my solution should give the correct values. If the camera can see both horizons at once, then Toby Marks solution will also give the correct answer, and probably with a bit less work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let us assume that the Earth's radius is $r = 6370 \text{ km}$. Then with the Earth's centre as the origin, the equation of the Earth's surface would be $x^2+y^2 = 6370^2$. The camera is $870$ km above, so it is at $(0, 6370 + 870) = (0, 7240)$.

Recall that the line $y = \tan \theta$ makes the angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis.  Since the angle to the $y$-axis is 63º, the angle to the $x$-axis is $90º - 63º = 27º$. The equation of the camera's view boundary therefore is given by the region between $y = (\tan 27º)x + 7240$ (left edge), and $y = -(\tan 27º)x + 7240$ (right edge). Substituting this in, we get $x^2 + ((\tan 27º)x + 7240)^2 = 6370^2$. The discriminant is $< 0$ so there are no solutions, and by symmetry, there are no solutions for the right half.

So for the maximum view distance, you need to find a point $E$ such that the line $CE$ that is tangent to the circle (touches only once). This means that $\angle CEB = 90º$. Therefore $\angle EBC = 90º - 63º = 27º$, so the total distance is $2r \theta$ as mathematics2x2life has said. Remember to convert $\theta$ into radians.

Comment: The way I read the problem, this tangle angle may not be achievable as the camera has a fixed width. You'd experience the same issue if you tried to use your cameraphone to take a photo of a large globe standing close to it, you will have a limited view and your view angles will not be tangent to the sphere.

Comment: I agree, but if we include the assumption that the camera has a fixed aperture, the problem gets slightly more messy. For the sake of the question, I am assuming the camera is a single point, and the Earth is assumed to be a perfect sphere.